# Calculating min, max without using a list

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to solve a problem from a python textbook:

Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of times that they have run around a racetrack, and then uses a loop to prompt them to enter the lap time for each of their laps. When the loop finishes, the program should display the time of their fastest lap, the time of their slowest lap, and their average lap time.

So far the concept of lists haven't been introduced but I can't think of a way to calculate the min, max lap time without using min(),max() on a list.

Here is my code:

```
num_laps = int(input('Enter number of laps you ran: '))


total_time = 0.0
lap_time_list = []

for lap in range(1,num_laps+1):
    lap_time = float(input('\nEnter the lap time in minutes for each lap from first to last: '))
    total_time += lap_time
    lap_time_list.append(lap_time)


avg_time = total_time / num_laps
fast_lap = min(lap_time_list)
slowest_lap = max(lap_time_list)

# Display the time of fastest lap, slowest lap and average lap time

print('\nAverage lap time:',avg_time,'mins')
print('\nFastest lap time:',fast_lap,'mins')
print('\nSlowest lap time:',slowest_lap,'mins')
```

Comment: You don't need a list, just keep track of the largest and smallest items you've seen. Same with the average, keep track of the total and number of items.

Comment: You should initialize 3 variables before entering the loop: `slowest_lap. fastest_lap, total_time`, On each loop you check if the newly entered lap is slower than the slowest lap and if it is it takes it's value, same thing with the fastest. At the same time increment  `total_time` by the number entered by the user, at the end you can calculate the average with that and the number of laps.

Comment: You can easily update min, max and avg times dynamically updating the max and min and using the last value and the lap count (for avg). But unless you have a good reason to, stick to lists: it is much more readable to see a `max` at the end of a loop than an `if` updating it constantly inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i think you can actually do this fairly simply, without a list. just keep track of the largest and smallest numbers seen so far.. right? not sure if this works but a simple example is something along the lines of:

```
num_laps = int(input('Enter number of laps you ran: '))

slowest, fastest, avg = 0, 1000, 0 # fastest just needs to be a very large number usually like a int.big

for lap in range(num_laps):
    lap_time = int(input('\nEnter the lap time in minutes for each lap from first to last: ')) # assumes round numbers
    if lap_time > slowest:
        slowest = lap_time
    if lap_time < fastest:
        fastest = lap_time
    avg += lap_time

avg /= num_laps
```

there's probably a bug in there somewhere, and edge cases to handle but the idea remains and you should be able to make it work correctly using the concept.

Comment: If I enter num_laps = 3 and 2, 4,7 as the lap times - The avg is calculated correctly as 4.333 and slowest lap time as 7 minutes but fastest lap is showing 1000.

Comment: ah ok like i said.. bugs .. try changing the `elif` to an `if`

Comment: Yeah. Adding changing elif to if is working. I think if the first if was true, then elif was being skipped in the previous version. Thanks.

Comment: @Cruise5 yup `elif` would never hit. i've also edited my original answer with that fix. if you found this helpful, please mark it accepted. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a "cache and dump" approach, where you check if the current entry is either the fastest or the slowest. If it's either case, replace the tracking variable with the current entry value.

```py
total_time = 0

for lap in range(1,num_laps+1):
    current_lap_time = eval(input("what's the lap time?"))

    # if it's the first lap, it will be our starting point
    if lap == 1:
        slowest_time = current_lap_time
        fastest_time = current_lap_time

    #check if the current lap time is the slowest
    if current_lap_time > slowest_time:
        slowest_time = current_lap_time

    # check if the current lap time is the fastest
    if current_lap_time < fastest_time:
        fastest_time = current_lap_time

    # calculate total time
    total_time += current_lap_time

# calculate average time
average_time = total_time / num_laps
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy; we can solve it without using a list; here is the code:

```
    enter Lap_count=int(input('How many laps you have taken'))
    slowest_lap=0.0
    Fastest_lap=0.0
    total=0.0
    for num in range(Lap_count) :
         print('This is the input for lap ', num+1,)
         lap_time = float(input('Enter the lap time:'))
         print('=======================================')
         if num == 0 :
             slowest_lap = lap_time
             Fastest_lap = lap_time
         total += lap_time
         if  slowest_lap > lap_time:
             slowest_lap = lap_time
         if Fastest_lap < lap_time:
             Fastest_lap = lap_time

        print('The fastest lap is:', Fastest_lap)
        print('The slowest lap is:', slowest_lap)
        print('The averages is:', format((total/Lap_count), '.2f'))
```